# How hibernate handles @Id during concurrent operations

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I am making a desktop app w/ db(microsoft sql) hosted in some server and hibernate on the top of db. Multiple users from multiple computers can manipulate/access data in a table and I want to know how Hibernate handles `@Id` when two or more different PCs executes perhaps `session.save(...)` simultaneously if `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` is used.
i.e

```
     @Entity
    @Table
    public class User{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;
        ......
    }
```

You can assume worst possible scenario i.e the save operation takes more than a minute and there's a lot of attributes in the class. Ik that Relational DBMS holds ACID property but i wanna know how? And is there anything i need to take care of before deploying the app?

Comment: the strategy used by AUTO depends on the database. It can be a sequence (in this case, the DB has an atomic counter), or an auto_increment column (the DB is in charge of assigning a different, incrementing ID to each row inserted), or a table-based sequence (Hibernate uses a separate database transaction to atomically get the next value in a table row and increment it).

Comment: Based on the database your are using and Hibernate version `AUTO` may be resolved to different Id generation strategies. What are you DB and Hibernate version?

Comment: Yes ik how @GeneratedValue works. I was asking what will happen if two or more users tries to insert a row in the same table simultaneously and assuming the worst case scenario, the db operations take time? Eg. session.save(...) from multiple users occurs at 1:30pm. Does one of the commit fails or something else?